# Button in variable didn't work when i clicked. Angular Typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript, variables

When i use this function:

```
@Pipe({name: "safeHtml"})
export class Save implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }

  transform(value: any) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------
```

```
FindTheResult(Group: string, Name: string) {

this.GetData().then(() => {
  this.ListOfName.forEach(name => {
    let Link = "Results/" + Group + "/" + name + "/" + Name
    this.FirebaseData.database.ref(Link).get().then(res => {
      if (res.val() == null) {

        this.tagName = `<h1>` + name + '</h1><h1>не приступал</h1>' + `<button (click)="Back()">dasds</button>` + this.tagName

      } else {
        this.tagName = this.tagName + `<h1>` + name + '</h1><h1>' + String(res.val()) + '%</h1>'
      }
    })
  })
})}
Back() {
this.IsTest = !this.IsTest}
```

I use this function to collect all data from a firebase. then i take all this stuff to variable 'tagName' and a button. But the button didn't work when i clicked.
P. s didn't work if i write this.Back() in (click)

Html:

```
<main>
      <div class="lable">
        <h1>My homework</h1>
        <div class="massive">
          <div style="pointer-events:none" [innerHTML]="tagName  | safeHtml"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
```

nothing happens. Seems it just does not see this function

Answer (score 0):

IMO the `bypassSecurityTrustHtml()` + `[innerHTML]` binding must only used in Angular if it couldn't be avoided. It doesn't support event handling such as `(click)="Back()"`.

I'd define an array and use it to contain the value. Then use `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` directives to render it in the template.

```js
public tags = [];

FindTheResult(Group: string, Name: string) {
  this.GetData().then(() => {
    this.ListOfName.forEach(name => {
      let Link = "Results/" + Group + "/" + name + "/" + Name
      this.FirebaseData.database.ref(Link).get().then(res => {
        this.tags.push({
          name: name, 
          value: res.val()
        });
      })
    })
  })
}

Back() {
  this.IsTest = !this.IsTest
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="lable">
    <h1>My homework</h1>
    <div class="massive">
      <div style="pointer-events:none">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let tag of tags">
          <h1>tag.name</h1>
          <h1 *ngIf="tag.value; else noBack">
            {{ tag.value }}
          </h1>
          <ng-container #noBack>
            <h1>не приступал</h1>
            <button (click)="Back()">dasds</button>
          </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Sidenote: I'm not sure how you'd click the button if the wrapping `<div>` has a `"pointer-events:none"`.

Comment: HOOOOOLY, Thanks. wooooow